# Is it possible to do this in SQL? For every instance, i want to count duplicate instances in past 60 days

Tags: sql, date, count, duplicates, lag

If child has a vanilla ice cream on few random days and chocolate ice cream on some other days, i want to create a final table which shows on any particular day, if i look back 60 days, how many times the child had that ice cream type

Data is first 2 columns and output desired is the third column

| type | Date | Count of instances in past 60 days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vanilla | 11/15/2022 | 2 |
| vanilla | 10/24/2022 | 2 |
| vanilla | 08/20/2022 | 1 |
| chocolate | 11/16/2022 | 2 |
| chocolate | 10/25/2022 | 2 |
| chocolate | 08/21/2022 | 1 |

I tried using floor(consecutive days diff/60) but that doesn't work in all instances because each month is not exactly 30 days.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired output and specify RDBMS you use

Comment: We cannot discern what your source data look like from the current version of your question. Also, please supply the query you've tried.

Comment: So the source data  is the first 2 columns and the output would be the count of duplicates. Also am at ideation stage and tried out logic in excel when i wondered if this can even be done in sql or i have to write a python loop. How can i add data here. When i copy from excel and paste in editor, it pastes as image

Comment: Please don’t use comments to add information, edit your question. Provide source data and the result you want to achieve based on that source data (both formatted as tables so they are easy to read) and provide the logic necessary to convert the source to the target

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some errors in your provided example. For example, **08/20/2022 and 10/24/2022 are more than 60 days away**, but you count it as consecutive in 60 days.

Regardless, based on your requirement description, you can use a [left outer join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) on input_date itself based on type and filter any result to between past 60 days interval to get the result you want.

Here is the [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gKP9aFATjchngNPDvmBNRC/0) in MySQL as an example:

```
select
   i1.type,
   i1.date,
   count(i2.type) + 1 as `Count of instances in past 60 days`
from
   input_data i1
left outer join
   input_data i2
on
   i1.type = i2.type
and
    DATEDIFF(i1.date,i2.date) between 1 and 60
group by
   i1.type,
   i1.date
order by
   i1.type desc,
   i1.date desc
```

| type | date | Count of instances in past 60 days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vanilla | 2022-11-15 | 2 |
| vanilla | 2022-10-24 | 1 |
| vanilla | 2022-08-20 | 1 |
| chocolate | 2022-11-16 | 2 |
| chocolate | 2022-10-25 | 1 |
| chocolate | 2022-08-21 | 1 |